# Why is my flash banner causing css issues?

Tags: html, css, flash

I have a flash banner ad that's being shown on a website as an ad at the bottom of the page. When the banner ad appears the scroll bar disappears. The following css is added to the page when the flash banner is present:

```
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;}
```

The "overflow: hidden" is causing the scroll bar issue, but I have no idea where it's coming from.

Is there any way a flash banner could affect the css on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem too. It seems when I publish a Flash Banner Ad onto googles Double Click studio, my flash ads are causing the scrollbar on the page that it gets loaded to to disappear. It seems to only be my ad, as the other ads in rotation do not do this.

```
body{
margin: 0;
overflow:hidden;
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? Did you try altering the publishing settings within Flash?

Comment: What we did was change the default.html template inside flash. Try that out and see if it helps.

Comment: Great idea. I wasn't sure how to change the default.html template inside flash, so I googled it and found information on how to do so in [this post](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/633854?start=0&tstart=0). I've updated the file and uploaded it to Double Click, so now we're just waiting to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow: hidden;` property on `body` tag causes anything outside current browser scope to be invisible, therefore the browser won't render any scrollbars. Remove this property and put it somewhere more acceptable, for example on a div where banner is present.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the actual HTML page. I'm just providing the swf. It appears as if the swf is injecting the css into the html page, but I have no idea how. Any ideas?

Comment: If the body tag has a `overflow: hidden` there is nothing else you can do. Whoever is responsible for it should fix it.

Comment: I noticed that when I publish the file through flash even the html file that is published has "overflow: hidden" in it, could something in the publishing setting cause this?

Comment: Not sure, it's hard to tell. If you or anyone else involved in developing the page didn't put it there then yes, it's probably caused by wrong configuration.